Sort table in order of entry
I have been digitizing some records for the company I work for, by entering some information from the forms in an Excel worksheet.
I made a mistake, and entered one column of information outside the table.
Ever since I sorted the table in any way, the information has been misaligned. Since the original documents were not in any specific order.
Is there some way to fully "unsort" the table back into the order I originally placed the information in?
Headers are:
A: Date;
B: Identifying Code;
G: Location;
H: Important Value 1;
And the column I accidentally entered outside the table:
J: Important Value 2
While I could simply redo the whole thing, there are 2000 entries in this table. I would greatly prefer a different solution.

From your daily backup?

Copying the data to a new sheet is possible but not useful. Columns A through H are sorted by date or whatver, whereas J is still on the order it appeared in the pile of documents I was working through

"information has been misaligned" Do you mean that data in one column no longer aligns on the correct row as other columns? As for sorting, click the column header to sort by Date, assuming that's the date entered.

If you didn't exit the file you should be able to use the undo button. If the file is autosaved then you should be able to revert to a previous version. Good luck.

Unless there is a key that can be sorted by, the answer is no, the system does not "know" the order in which you entered the data. The system assumes that if the order of entry was important, you would have data that records that order.
